# MUI Autocomplete Typescript: What is the type of PaperComponents function parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

MUI's Autocomplete has a property `PaperCompomponent` that allows you to pass your own react component. The property is a function that has `properties` as a parameter that can be used to pass it on to your component.

In Typescript, I would like to type the properties parameter. Does anyone know the exact type? It is not `PaperProps` which can be imported from MUI itself.
Autocomplete is using `React.JSXElementConstructor<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>>;` which seems to be the right one, but when accessing the `children`, I get a typescript error that `properties.children` does not exist in this type.

This is a very simple example to give you an idea of what I mean.

Autocompleter.tsx

```
 <Autocomplete
   id='autocompleter'
   PaperComponent={ (properties) => <Component properties={ properties } /> }
 />
```

Component.tsx

```
interface ComponentProps {
 properties: ???;
}

const Component: FunctionComponent<ComponentProps> = ({ properties }): ReactElement => (
 <Container onMouseDown={ properties.children[2].props.onMouseDown }>
   <div {...properties}>
   <div> Some Content</div>
 </Container>
))
```

Comment: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/92a4866ce9a06769592cddc06cfa7455b4644544/packages/mui-material/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.d.ts#L181

Comment: while hovering `(properties)` it says `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>`

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but I keep getting a typescript error that 'children' does not exist in that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create add the children prop:

```js
interface ComponentProps {
  // Obtained from the source code
  properties: React.JSXElementConstructor<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>>;

  // Additional prop
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Component: FunctionComponent<ComponentProps> = ({ properties, children }): ReactElement => (
  <Container onMouseDown={ properties.children[2].props.onMouseDown }>
    <div {...properties}>
    <div> Some Content</div>
  </Container>
))
```

You do not have to access the `children` prop through `properties`, it can be another from your component.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! This would work, but I also realized that the type ```React.JSXElementConstructor``` can be removed here to just use ```React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>```. Then I have children typed accordingly inside properties.